# Use Induction to Show $(1+a)^n \ge 1 + na$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

If $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$ $\ni$ $a > -1$, then ($\forall n$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$) ($(1+a)^n \ge 1 + na$)

My main concern is twofold: Firstly, I am concerned that constant $a$ in the proposition may force the proof into cases, even though some nmber crunching shows that this may not be true; lastly, I was wondering if the proof that I wrote is valid. Any hints or critiques will be enlightening.

**Base Cases**

Suppose $n = 1$. Then

\begin{align}(1+a)^n \ge 1+na 
\\ 1+a \ge 1+a\end{align}

Suppose $n = 2$. Then

\begin{align}(1+a)^n \ge 1+na 
\\ (1+a)^2 \ge 1+2a\end{align}

which is true, since $1+a > 0$.

**Induction Hypothesis**
$-$Suppose $(1+a)^n \ge 1 + na$.

To show that $\left(1+a\right)^\left(n+1\right)$ $\ge 1+a(n+1)$, we begin as follows

$$\begin{align}
\\
1+a(n+1) & = (1 + an ) + a \tag{distribute and commute}\\[0.5em]
         & \le (1+a)^n + a \tag{ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
         & \le (1+a)^n(1+a) \\
         & = \left(1+a\right)^\left(n+1\right)
\end{align}$$

as desired.

Comment: This is called Bernouli inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You want to show that
$(1+a)^{n+1}
\ge 1+(n+1)a
$.

The induction hypothesis is
$(1+a)^{n}
\ge 1+na
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
(1+a)^{n+1}
&= (1+a)(1+a)^n
\quad\text{(getting ready to use the
induction hypothesis)}\\
&\ge (1+a)(1+na)
\quad\text{(using the induction hypothesis and $1+a > 0$)}\\
&= 1+(n+1)a+na^2
\quad\text{(algebra)}\\
&\ge 1+(n+1)a
\quad\text{(and we are done)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I liked you proof @marty. I was wondering if you would inform me on how my proof was incorrect.

Comment: There is still a problem. You have $(1+a)^n+a \le (1+a)^n(1+a)$ which is the same as $a \le a(1+a)^n$, which is not necessarily true.